# Simple Javascript Quiz (trouble with global variables?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple javascript quiz, but its been difficult figuring out the scoring. I'm a beginner with javascript so bear with me. I'm creating a quiz that has a new question on a new page and the last page displays the score. Currently when I answer a question and go to the next page and the score resets. It's probably the variable I'm using but I don't know enough about javascript to fix it.

I have four buttons, one correct answer and three incorrect answers. The correct answer triggers and function that adds 1 to the variable x which is the score. The variable x is a global variable. So when I go to the next page to see the score the score resets at 0.

I'm trying to find a simple solution to this issue if possible. I condensed the code to one page for this post but the score is suppose to print the next page not the question page. Thank you to all who reads this!

```js
var x = 0;

function myFunctionCorrect() {
  x = x + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Correct!";
  document.getElementById("scoretext").innerHTML = "Your score is " + x + ".";
}

function myFunctionWrong() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Wrong!";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionCorrect()" class="elementbutton">Spandrel</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionWrong()" class="elementbutton">Attic</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionWrong()" class="elementbutton">Roundrel</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionWrong()" class="elementbutton">Plinth</button>
   
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="scoretext"></p>
```

Comment: Use localstorage to store the score and retrieve it in the second page.

Comment: Either store the score in localstorage, or pass the score in URL. Second one would be better :)

Comment: @DipankarMaikap Okay! Where would localstorage go into the code? Within a function? Or outside the function?

Comment: @PranavRustagi how would I pass the score in URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = 0;
function myFunctionCorrect() {
  x = x + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("score", x);
}

function showScore() {
var score=localStorage.getItem("score")
document.getElementById("scoretext").innerHTML = "Your score is " + score + ".";
      
}
```

You have to do something like this your `myFunctionCorrect` should store the value in local-storage and then  a function like `showScore` can retrieve the score from localstorage and show to user.

Comment: This is great! Now this is probably a weird question but I really don't know a lot of javascript. This code worked me for but I'm not sure how to show the score on the next page. I have the javascript in one page and the html page with the score I have <p id="scoretext"> </p> How do I show the score automatically without an onclick() button trigger?

Comment: One way would be ```<body onload="showScore()">``` add the function in your html body. Another option ```document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showScore);``` add this in your html footer with in a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your are moving to the next page, but javascript variables don't typically carry over from page to page, unless you were using frames or something and storing your JS in a parent frame.

Off the top of my head, I would persist the variables in the url, then parse then on the next screen.
If you were using a server-side language, I do it in a form instead.

Comment: @dipankar-maikap may have a better solution; I forgot about local storage (I don't use it), but it'll keep your variables out of the user's hands.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone here on persisting the variables in the URL. I know you mentioned you're a beginner--even variables with global scope don't persist across different pages, so you can pass the score into the URL when the score updates, perhaps through the URL's `hash`:

```
function myFunctionCorrect() {
  x = x + 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Correct!";
  document.getElementById("scoretext").innerHTML = "Your score is " + x + ".";
  let scoreHash = `score:${x}`
  window.location.hash = "scoreHash"
}
```

Then, when a new page loads, you can grab the hash from the referrer URL and re-declare it as your global `x` variable. So include this function at the top of your Javascript for each page:

```
var x;
document.onload = function() {
  let previousScore = document.referrer;
  x = previousScore
}
```