# Javascript Quiz Score saved to next pages

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to create a quiz with javascript, but I'm a beginner and I've been having issues with collecting score over different pages.

Here is the glitch I made to demonstrate my issue --> https://quiz-demo-score.glitch.me

Each page/question does the score but it isn't added together on the last page.

*I also had help from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378319/simple-javascript-quiz-trouble-with-global-variables/64378728?noredirect=1#comment113840397_64378728) on how to store the score in local storage and load on the last page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: You are getting into complex territory, as simple as it may seem. I'll suggest to try and make it a single page application, that way it will be much easier to keep track of the user's score or similar data, like name for example. Here is a video on how to make your own [Web Components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCWaFLy3VUo) it may seem a bit intimidating at first but the instructor is very good at explaining the concepts from scratch, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this is (indeed) to use [Local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You can keep the user's score inside a local storage object.

If you have any question about the use of local storage, feel free to ask.

#### Use case:

```
localStorage.setItem('userScore', 0);
```

And with every right answer/score +1 you can use:

```
const score = localStorage.getItem('userScore');
score++;
localStorage.setItem('userScore', score);
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response! I have a question about how to use this code. Where would it go within my existing code? Would this replace the x variable I'm using?

Comment: @blue-hippo-21 Yes the purpose of this is to fully replace your 'x'/score variable.